# How to prepend a string to the name of many columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with numerous columns, and I need to prepend the same string to the name of each of these columns.

Rather than doing

```
df.rename({"col1": "prepended_str_col1", ....., })
```

I was wondering if there is an easier way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to modify all columns or a subset?

Comment: @mozway Just a subset of columns.

Comment: OK, then it's the way to go, but make it easier with a dictionary comprehension (see my answer below), also don't forget to use `columns=` or you will act on the index ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Add a prefix to each column name

```
df = df.add_prefix('Prefix_')
```

Answer (score 1):

##### all columns

If you want to modify all columns, use [`add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = df.add_prefix('prepended_str_')
```

Example output:

```
  prepended_str_A prepended_str_B prepended_str_C prepended_str_D prepended_str_E prepended_str_F prepended_str_G prepended_str_H
0               X               X               X               X               X               X               X               X
```

##### subset of columns

For a subset, you can use a dictionary comprehension and [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
cols = ['A', 'C', 'E']
prefix = 'prepended_str_'
df = df.rename(columns={c: prefix+c for c in cols})
```

Example output:

```
  prepended_str_A  B prepended_str_C  D prepended_str_E  F  G  H
0               X  X               X  X               X  X  X  X
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame('X', index=[0], columns=list('ABCDEFGH'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [5, 6, 7, 8]})

df = df.add_prefix('col_')
print(df)
```